# Foreach + InnerHtml sacar un valor concreto

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un foreach donde se generan varios formularios y por cada uno hay un botón modificar, quiero al darle a ese botón modificar coger el input name="txtdireccion_mac" que le pertenece.

---HTML

```
 @foreach($datos_usuario as $value) 
                <tr>
                <form action="Borrar_mac" id="idformac_usu" name="formac_usu" method="POST" >
                    {!! csrf_field(); !!}
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtdireccion_mac" readonly="readonly" value="{!! $value->Direccion_mac !!}"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txt_descripcion" readonly="readonly" value="{!! $value->Descripcion !!}"  ></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="txtfecha" readonly="readonly" value=" {!! $value->Fecha !!} "  ></td>

                    <td><input type="button" name="modificar" onclick="cambiarMac(this)" value="Modificar Mac" ></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="btn_borrar" value="Borrar Mac"></td>

                </form>
                </tr>   
                  @endforeach   
            </table>

        <div id='formulario_cambio_mac'>

        </div>
```

### Javascript

```
 function cambiarMac(obj){
                var txt1 = "<form action='cambiar_datos_mac' method='POST'>";
                txt1 += "<input type='hidden' name='identificadormac' id='ididentificadormac' value=''>";
                txt1 += "Escribe la nueva Mac <input type='text' name='txtmac' value=''  ><br/>";
                txt1 += "Escribe la Descripcion  <input type='text' name='txtdescripcion' value='' ><br/>";
                txt1 += "<input type='submit' name='btn_enviar' value='Cambiar Mac'>";
                txt1 += "</form>";

                document.getElementById("formulario_cambio_mac").innerHTML = txt1;
                var mac=obj.value;
                document.getElementById('identificadormac').value = mac; 
            }
```

Con el campo hidden es para buscar en la bbdd la vieja mac y cambiarla por la nueva. El problema es que al darle al botón y pintar el formulario no sé como coger de ese formulario la dirección mac de esa fila.

Si hay una forma más sencilla o algo , estoy abierto a sugerencias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes generar un id dinamico con algun valor de tu consulta, como por ejemplo la mac actual, y le enviamos al a funcion `cambiarMac` la mac para que sepa como buscar el input. 
Por ejemplo:

```
@foreach($datos_usuario as $value) {

        <input type="text" name="txtdireccion_mac"

        // generamos id dinamico
        id="mac_{!! $value->Direccion_mac !!}"
        readonly="readonly" value="{!! $value->Direccion_mac !!}">

        <input type="button" name="modificar" 

        // le enviamos el id como parametro a la funcion cambiarMac
        onclick="cambiarMac(this,'mac_{!! $value->Direccion_mac !!}')" value="Modificar Mac" >
```

Entonces en tu funcion solo tendrias que recibir el parametro y buscar el input por el id enviado:

```
function cambiarMac(obj, idMac){

    var valueMacActual = document.getElementById(idMac).value;

    //...
}
```